# Detect When CollectionView is Refreshed

Tags: wpf, refresh, collectionview

How can I detect when a collection view has been refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to its [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.collectionchanged.aspx) and/or [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.propertychanged.aspx) events.
This is only possible if you casted it to either `INotifyCollectionChanged` or `IPropertyCollectionChanged` before.

Comment: Daniel's answer was on the correct track except for the fact both of those events are protected, so the only way to access them is via a new class that exposes those events.  Also, the CollectionChanged only gets called when the view is refreshed.  You should subscribe to the CollectionView's source to get adds, updates, and removes.